# Kotlin error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I followed [Get started with Kotlin/Native using the command-line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-command-line-compiler.html), downloaded [kotlin-native-linux-1.5.10.tar.gz](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.5.10/kotlin-native-linux-1.5.10.tar.gz) and added its `bin` to the `PATH` of system. Now `which kotlinc-native` returns true value.

But when I try `kotlinc-native hello.kt -o hello`, get this error:

```
~/.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-8.0.0-linux-x86-64/bin/clang++: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem and how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can manually install libtinfo.so.5 to your system

e.g Linux distro package manager

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```